# Using res.render x res.send

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

A few years ago, during my internship I had the opportunity to work with NodeJS and Angular. At the project I didn't know about view-engines, I just used res.send() and worked with Angular in each archive. Today I am doing some courses from Udemy in which the teacher use res.render() along a view engine (ejs, for example).

Was it a bad practice of mine by using res.send with HTML? Is it better using res.render() to pass archives with AngularJS?

I don't know if I made my doubt clear, but in other words...
What's the difference when I use res.render or res.send with or without a view-engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**res.render()** is used to return a rendered html file.

A template engine enables you to use static template files in your application. At runtime, the template engine replaces variables in a template file with actual values, and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client. This approach makes it easier to design an HTML page.

Ejs,Jade,Pug are some of the view engines.

**res.send()** can be used to send Buffer, String, an Object and an Array.

**res.json()** can be specifically to send json data client side.

In your case you only need to send json data to angular. So you can use res.json() or res.send(). res.json() has some extra features to format the json.

[Learn about render function](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render)

[Learn about template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

[res.send() vs res.json()](https://fullstack-developer.academy/res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express/)